# AM3352 Module How to start an application after MLO

Tags: u-boot

For AM3352 modules:

- How to start a application after MLO (1st stage of Boot loader) without starting the boot loader (u-boot)?
- How to start an application?

  - What are the prerequisites?

Answer (score 1):

When the next stage is to be loaded from a filesystem rather than a direct offset, the variable CONFIG_SPL_FS_LOAD_PAYLOAD_NAME controls what the first stage (SPL) will load and then jump to.  With regards to prerequisites and "starting an application", what is loaded must be a stand alone binary and handle everything that it needs and wants to do.

Comment: Briefly, because there is nothing else running except for your application and the hardware has only been very slightly configured.